# Can Win7 HP to access Server 2003 via RDP?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, rdp

I have the Remote Desktop Connection installed on Windows 7 HP, but when I type in the full server name of my Windows Server 2003 box, it fails to connect.  Can I fix this, or do I need Windows 7 Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues you're having are not due to the client OS version you're using.

Give us some more information about your setup and we may be able to help you get to the bottom of it.

Here are a few ideas to get you started:

- Have you tried typing in the IP address of the server instead of the DNS name?
- Have you enabled remote desktop on the server? If not, I believe the steps to enable are as follows. 1) Right-click on "My Computer" and select "Properties". 2) Click on the "Remote" tab and tick the "Enable Remote Desktop" item.

Comment: The IP address did the trick.  What name should I look for to type in the box instead of an IP? the Computer name? the server name? Thanks!

Comment: If you have a DNS system set up, you'll need to create a DNS A record for the server. If you don't have DNS set up, you may be able to do name resolution via NetBIOS, but it's not foolproof. With NetBIOS, you'd just type in the server's hostname.